# how to find file name ignoring case sensitivity in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep, ls

In my case there is a possibility of getting files like abb_Timestamp.csv or ABC_TIMESTAMP.CSV. I am using `ls -l | grep ABC* | wc -l`. I want the count of files irrespective of the case. even If I get files in CAPITAL Letter I should get the Count and even if I get in Small letters I should get the count in unix. Please Suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parsing the output of `ls` is considered [bad practice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You can use `find`:

```
find . -iname 'ABC*' | wc -l
```

`man find`:

```
  -iname pattern
          Like -name, but the match is case insensitive.  For example, the
          patterns `fo*' and `F??' match  the  file  names  `Foo',  `FOO',
          `foo',  `fOo',  etc.   In these patterns, unlike filename expan‐
          sion by the shell, an initial '.' can be matched by  `*'.   That
          is, find -name *bar will match the file `.foobar'.   Please note
          that you should quote patterns as a matter of course,  otherwise
          the shell will expand any wildcard characters in them.
```

As **Johnsyweb** notes in the comment, `find` will recurse into subdirectories by default. To avoid that, you can supply `-maxdepth 1`:

```
   -maxdepth levels
          Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of direc‐
          tories below the command line arguments.  -maxdepth 0
           means only apply the tests and  actions  to  the  command  line
          arguments.
```

Comment: N.B: Supply `-maxdepth 1` to `find` otherwise this recurses into subdirectories, where the command in the question does not.

Comment: Thanks for the attribution, but it wasn't me.

Answer (score 0):

man grep:

```
$ echo "FOO" | grep foo

$ echo "FOO" | grep -i foo
FOO
$ echo "FOO" | grep -c -i foo
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk.
Search all files with csv/CSV and count hits, with one awk.

```
ls -l  | awk 'tolower($9)~"csv" {a++} END {print a}'
```

Comment: This will fail for filenames with spaces

Comment: Its just an example, you could use tolower($0)~"csv".